# Add footer to keycloak login page

Tags: css, keycloak

What's the correct way to add a text footer (copyright) to the keycloak login page ? Do I need to overwrite the whole template, or is there a way to include the current login.ftl ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/OSC/keycloak-theme/tree/master
here there are files related to login and theme of keycloak that you can edit and customize them.
also you can make your own theme.